# Split image based on thin lines with CV2 in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to split the image below in different blocks according to thin horizontal lines that you can see (follow the red arrows).
I tried to modify the different parameter but I'm still not able to detect them, do you know how can I proceed ? My goal is to identify 4 blocs:

- the header with the "Combiné" text
- 1 block for each bet
- the footer with the betting odd and the expected gain

Here is my code, I tried to modify the height / weight of the line but I m not able to detect them:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Charger l'image
image = cv2.imread('polygone_resultant.png')

# Convertir l'image en niveaux de gris
gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Appliquer un seuillage pour détecter les lignes grises claires
_, binary_image = cv2.threshold(gray_image, 220, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)  # Ajuster la valeur du seuil

# Appliquer la détection de contours
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary_image, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Initialiser une liste pour stocker les blocs de texte
text_blocks = []

# Parcourir les contours pour extraire les lignes horizontales fines
for contour in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    # Vérifier si le contour correspond à une ligne horizontale fine
    if h < 3 and w > 50:  # Ajuster les valeurs de hauteur (h) et de largeur (w) en fonction de vos besoins
        text_block = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        text_blocks.append(text_block)

# Afficher chaque bloc de texte
for i, block in enumerate(text_blocks):
    cv2.imshow(f'Text Block {i+1}', block)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Regards,

Thomas

Comment: Threshold on the color of the lines. Then find the locations of the non-zero pixels (lines)

Comment: Calculate row-based medians, the gray lines are rows where median is less than 255. (`np.where(np.median(gray_image, axis=1) < 255)`) Might want some low-end threshold as well, for situations where there is lot of text, so median becomes black. Might also want to do some simple clustering on the result, since the horizontal lines seem to be 3 pixels thick.

Comment: Here's a quick prototype: https://pastebin.com/Ys1YsqVS

Comment: @DanMašek, thank you very much, that helps me a lot !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained by @fmw42 simple thresholding can solve your problem:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2
import numpy as np

img_path = "test.png"
img = cv2.imread(img_path)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray[gray<255] = 0

col_idxs = np.where(np.sum(gray, axis=1)==0)[0]
# Remove adjacent elements
differences = np.diff(col_idxs)
mask = np.concatenate(([True], differences > 2))

filtered_col_idxs = col_idxs[mask]

imgs = []
past_col = 0
for col_idx in filtered_col_idxs:
    im = img[past_col:col_idx]
    imgs.append(im)
    cv2.imwrite(f"cropped_{past_col}_{col_idx}.png", im)
    past_col = col_idx
```

Here are the results:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you !